# How to write query for groupby clause in dynamo db with past 30 days

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How to get past 30 days data using dynamo db with group by clause(power).
Having table name lightpowerinfo with fields like id, lightport, sessionTime, power.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon DynamoDB is a **NoSQL database**, which means that it is not possible to write SQL queries against the data. Therefore, there is no concept of a `GROUP BY` statement.

Instead, you would need to **write an application** to retrieve the relevant raw data, and then calculate the results you seek.

Comment: then i need to fetch the all data from table and need to workout right?

Comment: You don't need to fetch ALL the data -- you could fetch a subset based on your Partition and Sort Keys (eg the past 30 days) and then perform calculations across that. It all depends on how you've designed your table schema and indexes.

Comment: I am new to dynamo db .I am getting id 350 in my items. How can i get all the items list past 30 days? Below is the code. $sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('30 days')); echo $response = $dynamodb->query([ 'TableName' => 'notifications', 'KeyConditionExpression' => 'id = :id and date_time >= :datess', 'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [ ':id' => ['S' => '350'], ':datess' => ['S' => $sevenDaysAgo] ], 'ProjectionExpression' => 'id', 'ConsistentRead' => true ]);

Comment: @user3445588 Please submit a new Question since this is different to your initial Question. This will encourage other people to respond.